# Accessing numbers inside square brackets in CSV file with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Let's say I have this kind of file.

[image: data]

How do I access the numbers in the 'helpful' column? I need the numbers separately. Preferably if I can actually store them in `helpful_1` and `helpful_2` columns.

I can do something like this.

[image]

But to be honest I don't really like this way. I don't think it's the best practice either. It's a pretty large file, by the way (~2GB), so this may not be the best way to do it. Maybe there's better way to access this as dataframe? Any ideas?

Also I wonder what square brackets in CSV are considered as. Are they some kind of lists? Or it doesn't mean anything?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I have answered my question below. But I am still open for some new suggestion as I am not exactly sure of my own solution. If there is a more elegant and efficient solution, I'd really like to know. Also, thanks for everyone who has commented/answered, every help is much appreciated.

Comment: using a plain [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) (as opposed to `pandas`) you could access the rows in your csv one by one.`[0,1]` will be treated as the string `'[0,1]'` with this reader.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist but will that still load as dataframe?

Comment: no, `dataframe`s are specific to `pandas`. this would just help rearrange your csv. (you could read the old one and transform it to a new one. but it seems that will not solve your problem... sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

## EDIT To handle strings:

```
df_out = df.assign(**df.helpful.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(eval(x))).rename(columns={0:'helpful_1',1:'helpful_2'}))
```

You could do soemthing like this:

```
df.assign(**df.helpful.apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'helpful_1',1:'helpful_2'}))
```

Output:

```
   helpful  number  helpful_1  helpful_2
0   [0, 1]       1          0          1
1   [0, 3]       2          0          3
2   [5, 6]       3          5          6
3  [8, 10]       4          8         10
4   [2, 5]       5          2          5
```

Comment: I think that should work, but it doesn't work for me. It displays the whole [0,1] in both the new columns instead. I have no idea why, I am still working on it.

Comment: Also I think it's worth noting that the square brackets here are apparently considered string, as I opened it on vi it's written as "[0, 1]".

Comment: @AnnaRG Yes, your columns are probably dtype object meaning they are strings.  I edited the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is really nice, maybe a bit improve is possible - add parameter `expand=True` to [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for output as `DataFrame`, cast to `int` both columns together:

```
df[['helpful_1', 'helpful_2']] = df['helpful'].str.strip('[]')
                                              .str.split(',', expand=True)
                                              .astype(int)
print (df)
  helpful  number  helpful_1  helpful_2
0   [0,1]       1          0          1
1   [0,3]       2          0          3
2   [5,6]       3          5          6
3  [8,10]       4          8         10
4   [2,5]       5          2          5
```

Comment: Thanks. But what does the parameter `expand=True` add to the code?

Comment: it create dataframe from output and then is possible assign it to new columns like `df[['helpful_1', 'helpful_2']]`

Comment: if test `df1 = df['helpful'].str.strip('[]')
                                              .str.split(',', expand=True)
                                              .astype(int)` it return `DataFrame` with 2 columns.

Comment: Oh I got. That's why when I put the `.astype(int)` directly behind the `split()` without the `expand=True` yesterday it didn't work. Now I know why. Thank you!

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Answer (score 0):

After some reading, I finally did the following.

```
df['helpful_1'], df['helpful_2'] = df['helpful'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',', 1)
```

Basically, I stripped down the square brackets first, and then I split it by a comma, then they are stored into two separate columns.

And then because I need them as int not as string, I converted them this way.

```
df['helpful_1'] = df['helpful_1'].astype(int)
df['helpful_2'] = df['helpful_2'].astype(int)
```

But I am not exactly satisfied, maybe there are better solutions, but this is all that works for now. I do think that maybe my code still has room for some improvement. If you can think of a more elegant and efficient way, please do tell me. I'm open for all new suggestions.